# Ufw default rules

Tags: firewall, rules, ufw

I have Debian public server with enabled ufw. This is utw's current rules:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

 To                         Action      From
 --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Nginx Full                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 7777/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    45.77.78.98               
[ 4] 2011                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 2011/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] 7777/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 8] 2011 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 9] 2011/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[10] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    217.118.78.0/24/tcp
```

There is no any rules for allowing port 8080. But. Nonetheless this port is actually accessible via ordinary http browser request like http://a.b.c.d:8080
Ufw default config file (/etc/default/ufw) has not been edited, so default input policy must drop any not explicitly allowed requests as I understand right, it has:

```
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="DROP"
```

If I add explicit deny rule for 8080 port:
ufw deny 8080/tcp
then requests like http://a.b.c.d:8080 became blocked, as it expected.

My question is why 8080 port is not blocked by default? Should I explicitly block all ports on my server by explicit rule like 'utw deny all'?

Answer (score 0):

I understood the reason. Just my browser ip address falls into the admission rule 10:

```
  [10] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    217.118.78.0/24/tcp
```